# property file configuration

Tags: java, logging, properties, log4j

One of the property files has following key-value pair.

log4j.Myapp.loglevel={{*appLogLevel|||ERROR*}}

Can anyone tell me, what is the meaning of the below code?

`{{*appLogLevel|||ERROR*}}`